# Returning string from a dropDownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have what is a very elementary problem I realize, I am trying to return a string value from a selected value of a DropDownList upon selected index change but for some or other reason it is not happening.

```
 protected void drpMinisters_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    name = drpMinisters.SelectedValue;
    LabMessage.Text = name;

}
```

When I try to add name to a database I get a NullReferenceException.

Advice perhaps

Comment: Does your LabMessage.Text show as empty/null ? if not your problem lies somewhere else in your code.

Comment: How you try to add name to database?

Comment: Post your data base code please

Comment: `labMessage.Text=drpMinisters.SelectedValue.ToString();` if you want to store the value else `labMessage.Text=drpMinisters.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();` also check your insert code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess you are talking about the asp.net dropdown list control

use drpMinisters.Text to get the selected value
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.text.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this if you are using ASP .net
var ddValue=
**document.getElementById("your Drop Down List Item").options[document.getElementById("your Drop Down List Item").selectedIndex].text;**
I was facing same problem it solved my problem with

"NullReferenceException"

Comment: Why javascript when he is trying from server side :-o